# How to add Visual3D object to UIElement3D using AddVisual3DChild method of the Visual3D Class

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-framework-version

I have a class which has `UIElement3D` as its base class. Normally I can update the `Visual3DModel` to add a `Model3D` element in it but I also want to add a `Visual3D` type object to my `UIElement3D`. In the `Visual3D` class there is a function call `AddVisual3DChild` using which I suppose we can add Visual3D objects. The problem is that when I use the `AddVisual3DChild` method to add an element of type `Visual3D` to the `UIElement3D` it does not add any thing. It would help alot if someone could tell me how to use it. Thank you for your time.

What I want to do is to add a `Visual3D` object to my `UIElement3D` object and it goies as follows:

```
public MyClass: UIElement3D
{
     public MyClass(Visual3D Object3D)
        {
            this.AddVisual3DChild(Object3D);
        }
}
```

Comment: AddVisual3DChild is a method of Visual3D, which is not a base class of UIElement. You probably want to derive your class from UIElement3D.

Comment: Im sorry I meant to write UIElement3D. But it is just not working how I imagined it to.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details to: "I am not being able to use it properly"? What does that mean? Side note: don't name your parameter object, because its a type in c#

Comment: @TheTanic The problem is that when I try to add an element of type `Visual3D` for example `ModelVisual3D` to the Children Property of `Visual3D` using the Method `AddVisual3DChild` provided by the same class `Visual3D` it  does not add the `ModelVisual3D` to the `Visual3D`. And you are right I mistakenly wrote object as my parameter let us just say its Object3D.

Comment: Its really hard to follot your explanation. Please edit your question, with your informations and add all the relevant code (Your Visual3D class at least with the AddVisual3DChild" method.